# Serialization/Deserialization callback in classes marked as [RemoteClass]

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, amf

I have been working on Flex project that uses value objects (VO) for manipulating data on client side. VOs are populated with the help of [RemoteClass] tag before a class definition.

The database structure was optimized, so as a result these are tables with fields like:

optionsName: "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"

In scope of project this value ("1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6") means a dynamic set of numbers.

By default optionsName class field populated with the string "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6" and it works fine. But I use this field as a set of number corresponding to business logic and it is more convenient to operate them as Array of Number instances. In general the best solution for this is subscribe to serializing/deserialized-like events of VOs and perform the additional conversion.

The question is: how can achieve this in Flex/ActionScript?

I understand that I could do this when result is arrived from remote object, but it is not good solution from my point of view. Also I know about solution with implementing flash.utils.IExternalizable interface.

The main idea is to force Flex to invoke the needed method before serialization and after deserialization of VOs.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Viktor Burdeinyi

Comment: I don't understand why you need a callback... what is that callback going to do?  Why are you just sending straight DB info to Flex?  Why not add a server layer that translates the data into a proper VO for easier serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write that property as a setter that supports Strings and Arrays as input and converts on the fly.

```
private var _optionsName:Array;
public function get optionsName():Array { return _optionsName; }
public function set optionsName(newOptionsName:*):void {
    if(newOptionsName is String) {
        _optionsName = newOptionsName.split(", ");
    } else {
        _optionsName = newOptionsName as Array;
    }
}
```